# Отправка динамичных данных в php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код на добавление div элементов, в которых содержаться input со значениями. Как взять данных из этих созданных input и передать в таблицу. Заранее спасибо.

```js
var p = document.getElementById("inputi");
var length = 1;

function add_input_from_select(select) {
  var new_input = document.createElement("input");
  new_input.name = "my_input";
  new_input.value = select.value;
  if(!new_input.value) return false;
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<br>div элемент №' + length + '<br>';
  div.appendChild(new_input);
  p.appendChild(div);
  length++;
}

function add_input_old() {
  add_input_from_select(document.getElementById("selector"));
}
```

```html
<select id="selector" onchange="add_input_from_select(this)">
  <option value="">Выберите значение</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<form>
  <div id="inputi"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: В __какую__ таблицу?

Comment: @u_mulder база данных